# Gmail labels or folders

Tags: adobe-flash

Does anyone know how to create a new label using an Android Tab s.
I have tried all the Internet pages with no success. 
Kind regards
Paul

Answer (score 2):

You have to log into you Gmail account on a PC (or via Chrome/Browser etc) and create the label from there.

You can't create labels using the Gmail app unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

To Add a label to your gmail in other email accounts you own

Open chrome
Invoke gmail
This will bring you to mobile browser
Tap three dots in corner
Select go incognito
Invoke gmail again
Sign in
Clock 3 straight lines (top left)
Scroll down and select desktop
Add label as you would on computer